# Batch edit one contact field (source) with same information

Tags: import, database, fields

I have over 50,000 contacts that I would like to batch-edit with the same contact "source" information. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I'd write a tiny php script but you could use the api explorer under `civicrm/api`:

1. Chose entity contact and action get
2. Add your search criteria
3. Add option "limit" to something high enough (Defaults to 25) or combine with option "offset"
4. Hit "chain api call"
5. Chose entity contact and action create
6. Enter json like "{source: 'your source'}"
7. Run

You could test it with one contact by adding it's id in the get criteria.

Comment: Christia, did you figure it out?